# ¿Cómo es posible que no funcione la ruta?

Tags: php

disculpen tengo una duda, estoy haciendo un sitio para guardar tareas de los alumnos en red local, por el cual hago la ruta en base al registro del alumno, pero algo muy raro sucede cuando hago la ruta, de esta manera la pagina funciona muy bien:

```
$root_dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\archivos\1\A\Artes\Rigoberto';
```

pero cuando hago esto, no reconoce la ruta:

```
$Materia = 'Artes';
$root_dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\archivos\1\A\'.$Materia.'\Rigoberto';
```

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar de favor?

Comment: Una pequeña consulta, cómo está esto relacionado con PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Bueno una disculpa, el código que puse ahí es para simplificar mas el comprendimiento de mi consulta la variable materias se toma de PHPMyAdmin

Comment: No te preocupes, entiendo que a veces, sobretodo cuando uno empieza, puede ser confuso. Pero debo mencionarte que PHPMyAdmin es una herramienta de administración de bases de datos, construida en PHP para, en principio, interactuar con MySQL y/o MariaDB, por lo que no es un motor de bases de datos, sino que es una aplicación web la cual se comunica con ellos para interactuar más gráficamente y, en la mayoría de los casos, de una manera mucho más fácil que con una aplicación de consola

Comment: Muchas gracias lo tendre en cuenta mi brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Actualización

Si bien lo comentado anteriormente es útil para el caso concreto, esto sólo sería funcional si el script se ejecuta en Windows. Para futuras referencias, recomiendo el uso de la **constante predefinida** `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, documentada [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dir.constants.php)

---

El problema, es que `\` es un caracter utilizado para indicar que la expresión/caracter siguiente es literal.

Está en inglés, pero [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764729/how-do-you-make-a-string-in-php-with-a-backslash-in-it#4764748) te puede orientar sobre cómo usar backslashes.

Por ende, deberías añadir un backslash, para indicar que el backslash de la cadena es **literal**, así:

```php
$root_dir = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\archivos\\1\\A\\'.$Materia.'\\Rigoberto';
```

Quedaría como `\\`.

Adicionalmente, te dejo la manera de hacerlo usando **comillas dobles**:

```php
$root_dir = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\archivos\\1\A\\$Materia\\Rigoberto";
```

Comment: Intentare esta manera, gracias por tu tiempo brother

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberia ser de este modo

```
$Materia = "Artes";
$root_dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/archivos/1/A/".$Materia."/Rigoberto/";
```

Comment: Si bien el caracter `/` es suficiente en la mayoría de los casos, en Windows, las rutas se especifican con backslash de manera predeterminada

Comment: Gracias brother

Comment: @KBeDev eso no significa que usar / traiga problemas o si ?

Comment: @Excorpion Eso ya depende de la configuración local del sistema que esté ejecutando el programa. La constante `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` existe precisamente por ese motivo. La especificación de la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats) estándar de Windows establece el uso del backslash como caracter separador.Ahora bien, y esto ya es opinión, se debería usar slash, pero Windows no funciona así, es la excepción a la regla, ya que sigue implementándolo como solución de compatibilidad, muy distinto de los sistemas POSIX.